# How to Ignore files with a given prefix?

Tags: c++, regex, astyle

Using astyle, I want to make it skip the files generated by qt's MOC as for some reason this files make astyle crash.

I'm using a simple convention of using the `moc_` prefix for those files.

Is there a way to globally configure astyle to ignore those files?

Which other strategy do you use to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "--exclude" option to skip processing specific files or directories.

Here is a link to the astyle documentation (search for exclude):
http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html